# How to display data from two table according to customer id in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to display data from 2 tables where 1 is customer and 2 is searches:

```
select product_id,product_name,product_price,customer_name,email,date_of_birth,
country,state,city,postcode from searches, customer where searches.customer_id = 
customer.customer_id and customer_id='1';
```

I am writing this query but facing the error:

> 13:06:03   select product_id,product_name from searches, customer where searches.customer_id =  customer.customer_id and customer_id='1' LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 1052. Column 'customer_id' in where clause is ambiguous 0.000 sec

Comment: and customer_id='1'  you need to qualify customer_id with table name.

Answer (score 0):

Tryed a left join ?

```
SELECT s.product_id, s.product_name, s.product_price, c.email, c.date_of_birth, c.country, c.state, c.city, c.postcode FROM searches AS s
        LEFT JOIN customer AS c 
        ON s.customer_id = c.id
        WHERE c.id = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

If a column name is strictly the same between two tables that you join together, you will always need to specify the table name (or alias) before the column name in order to let it know which field is concerned (from which table).

This is why it tells you "Column 'customer_id' in where clause is ambiguous" because it doesn't know if it is customer_id from customer table or searches table.

Solution is :

```
SELECT 
  product_id,
  product_name,
  product_price,
  customer_name,
  email,
  date_of_birth,
  country,
  state,
  city,
  postcode 
FROM searches s
JOIN customer c ON s.customer_id = c.customer_id 
WHERE c.customer_id='1';
```